# Core Data and didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

i'm trying to learn to use core data in my apps. how ever i'm stuck here at didSelectRowAtIndexPath

i want to be able to use my uitableview as i did before if possible

arrayA is a nsarray filled from a plist. and i can't figure out how to change this code to work with Core Data

in my core data i have HovedMenu BarneDaab and Graviditeten they all got attributes with menuPunkt that has strings in them. so the question is how do i get this code to work with core data ?

i think the arrayA has to change **ofc**, but to what ? 
this is the old code i used when i loaded from plist. **i want to upgrade it to core data**

```
if ([arrayA[indexPath.row][@"menuPunkt"]isEqualToString:@"Barnedåb"]) {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"BarneDaab" bundle:nil];
    barneDaabMenuViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"barneDaab"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

}
```

Here's my fected :

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
MBBAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MBBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext* context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Hovedmenu" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"menuPunkt" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:nil];

self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

}

Comment: You're using the FRC to populate the cell with info? So you get the appropriate object then?

Comment: @Wain yes i do get the appropriate object. into the table it's some what in the wrong order totally but that's not the main issue here :)

Comment: So why do you need the array when you have the FRC. And access to the objects it holds?

Comment: @Wain array where ? i need a way to get that code to work and have no idea what and where

Comment: i need a way to have the tableview use IsEqualToString or something so i know what table row to interact with

Comment: self.menuArray and arrayA. I'm really not clear on what source of data you want to use and what you want to do with it. I can see 3 different data sources in your code. You want to check the text of a selected row and show a controller, but from the FRC?

Comment: @Wain self.menuArray i have deleted. arrayA was the old code that i'm trying to update to use with FRC... i just have no clue on how to update it to use core data . hence why i'm asking here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it would seem that all you need to do is to replace `arrayA[indexPath.row][@"menuPunkt"]` with a call to the FRC to get the appropriate object (just like you do to update the cell contents).

```
[[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] valueForKey:@"menuPunkt"]
```

(You need to change the reference method for @"menuPunkt" because you used to have dictionaries and now you have managed objects so the syntactic sugar doesn't work).

Comment: Xcode wanted me to add a extra [ at the beginning before self. and it throw a error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Hovedmenu objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a805b0'

Comment: Ah, my bad, 1 minute.